# tcolorbox minted doesnot break python docstring

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, python

I try to produce boxed minted code in Python, and it does not break Python docstring. I have tried different `break...` options, unsuccessfully.

MVE as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}
\newtcblisting{pythoncode}{
  listing engine=minted,
  breakable,
  listing only,
  nobeforeafter,
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=python,
  enhanced,
  minted options = {
        breaklines=true, 
        %breakanywhere=true,
        %breakbytoken=true,
        %breakbytokenanywhere=true,
        %breakbefore=.                   
      },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pythoncode}
def make_segments(sig, segment_size=100, buffer=10):
    """
    The function takes in a 1-dimensional array and splits it into segments of a specified size. The segments are created with a constant step between them, determined by the buffer parameter.
    """
    pass
\end{pythoncode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Line breaking works if you remove `minted style=colorful`. Might be a bug in the style.

Comment: @Sergei Golovan
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @SergeiGolovan The colorful style uses `\colorbox` for such docstrings. This is unbreakable.  It is not in itself a bug of the style but a feature of `\colorbox`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was resolved in comments.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to turn @user691586 an@Sergei Golovan's comments into an answer?